# Getting all possible Linear Combinations of a matrix R

Tags: r, matrix

suppose I have the following augmented matrix

```
100 100 0   100
325 0   500 500
```

In equation terms:

```
c1(100) + c2(100) + c3(0) = 100
c1(325) + c2(0) + c3(500) = 500
```

I cannot change the final column.
How do I find all possible linear combinations?
The obvious solution is c2 = 1 and c3 = 1.
But how do I get it in a systemic manner?

I tried using rref in the pracma package but I get

```
1 0  1.538462   1.5384615
0 1 -1.538462  -0.5384615
```

I really can't have any fraction values.

Any advice?

Comment: You have 2 equations and 3 variables -> cannot be solved analitically. You have to use numeric methods, which may return none or infinite values. If you want your values to be integer as well... that's even worse.

Comment: What do you mean by numeric methods?

Comment: Numerical approximation algorithms which return approximate answers usually based on some iterative procedure.

Comment: You're suggesting brute force :(

Noooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
I guess for my case: limit all c's from 0:2 and then try every combo.
(I can't have any negative's either.)

Answer (score 2):

This is an underdetermined system of linear equations. You can get all its solutions with the help of the Moore-Penrose inverse of `A`. Let `Ainv` be the Moore-Penrose inverse of `A`. Then all solutions of `A %*% x = b` are given by `Ainv %*% b + (I - Ainv %*% A) %*% w` where `I` is the identity matrix and `w` is any vector.

```
A <- rbind(c(100,100,0), c(325,0,500))
b <- c(100,500)

Ainv <- MASS::ginv(A)

w <- c(1,2,3) # arbitrary
one_solution <- Ainv %*% b + (diag(3L) - Ainv %*% A) %*% w

A %*% one_solution
#      [,1]
# [1,]  100
# [2,]  500
```

Comment: What is v (any vector)? What is the final output?

Comment: @user2974951 What do you mean by "the final output" ? There are infinitely many solutions, and you get one solution for each vector `w`.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I still have to go through various combinations of w until A %*% one_solution == b & one_solution only consists of integers?

This seems like more convoluted brute force.